# Pandas : store each row data into a dictionary with column name as key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the below csv/excel data

```
uniqueid  name   age  marks

efsdf     David  20   80

fdsdf     Mark   23    

sdfs      John        40
```

sometimes values can be missed in cells, but uniqueid must be there, according to uniqueid provided I will update data in database
I want to store every row data into dictionary and pass into a method like

```
dict = {
 "uniqueid":"efsdf",
 "name" : "David",
 "age" : "20",
  "marks":"80"
}
```

this is the method-> updatevalue(dict). for each row, I need to do this(pass dictionary to method).

How to do this for every row and also get the column names as keys into dictionary for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need `.apply` method:

```
df.apply(lambda x: updatevalue(x.to_dict()), axis=1)
```

More infromation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html